# How I can import a matrix without delimiters to python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a .geno file, what is basically a matrix with 0-1-2-9 numbers. I try to import it for further analysis to python. It looks like this:

```
0      1010111011011020001111111010011100012020110011...
1      1211101021010220201112100010110111111020120001...
2      0111110111211112211110111212212121210201111212...
3      2212222121222110111221222110111111222211222211...
4      0000000000000000100010000000000010100000010000...
```

It's basically a matrix with 2054 columns with a lot of rows, but without delimiters. With pandas I can import it with:

```
full_geno = pd.read_csv('22_chr.geno')
```

But It will be just one column. With numpy it said all the values are inf. What could be the solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solved my problem :)

```
   len = [1]*2054
   full_geno = pd.read_fwf("22_chr.geno", widths=len, header=None)
```

Comment: I would suggest not using `len` as a variable name, since `len()` is a built-in function in python.